# setInterval() speeding/slowing function propagation after a few cycles

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` to cycle through a carousel of 4 images. On initial page load, the functions seem to work as expected. However, after a few cycles and hovers, focusing out of the page, the cycle starts speeding up between a couple of images and remains fine within the other. Sometimes, it starts skipping images all together in the cycle. At times it also autocorrects and starts working fine again. Here's what I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var count = -1;
var maxCount = $('.hero-blocks .block').length;
var colors = new Array('yellow', 'blue', 'promo', 'purple');
var autopager, timer = false;
var desktop = false,
    mobile = false;


function carousel() {
    if(count < maxCount - 1) {
        count++;
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }

    $('.hero-blocks .block.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.hero-blocks .block.' + colors[count] + '').addClass('active');

};

function startAutopager() {
    autopager = window.setInterval(carousel, 4000);

    timer = true;
}

function stopAutopager() {
    window.clearInterval(autopager);
    $('.hero-blocks .block').removeClass('active');

    timer = false;
}

function triggerCarousel() {
    if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 1024px)')) {
        // This stuff stops the carousel if the user goes to a different tab
        if(!desktop) {
            startAutopager();
            window.addEventListener('focus', startAutopager);
            window.addEventListener('blur', stopAutopager);

            desktop = true;
            mobile = false;

            $('.hero-blocks .block').hover(function() {
                stopAutopager();
            }, function() {
                startAutopager();
            });
        }
    } else if(!mobile) {
        stopAutopager();

        mobile = true;
        desktop = false;
    }
}
triggerCarousel();

$(window).resize(function() {
    triggerCarousel();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that it's possible to call `window.setInterval(carousel, 4000)` multiple times, since it's triggered during a couple of different events, and the code doesn't check if it's already running.

I suggest checking the value of `timer` before calling `setInterval`

```
function startAutopager() {
    if (!timer) {
        autopager = window.setInterval(carousel, 4000);

        timer = true;
    }
}

function stopAutopager() {
    if (timer) {
        window.clearInterval(autopager);
        $('.hero-blocks .block').removeClass('active');

        timer = false;
    }
}
```

Another minor point - `setInterval` doesn't guarantee perfect timing, so it's still possible that `carousel` will be triggered with different intervals.

Comment: Setting the timer is definitely going to improve this (timer isn't really being used for anything otherwise). The minor point actually explains quite a lot of it!